# Routing in ReactNative and ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-v4

I want to develop an application using React and ReactNative, and also React-Router.
Please help me to organize a routing in native apps, since I'm a newbie in that.

If it's possible to use the same file for routing both in web and native, it would be fantastic.

This is a code snippet written for web part:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './utils/History';

import store from './store/configureStore';
import Root from './containers/Root';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Root/>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

As you can see, I use a custom history for my app, this is how 'utils/History.js' file looks:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

All does work pretty well in web browser, but it does not in iOS emulator:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the **[docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router)**, you need to import `Router` from `react-router` package and not `react-router-dom`.

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Router} from 'react-router';
import history from './utils/History';

import store from './store/configureStore';
import Root from './containers/Root';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Root/>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham, you gave me a right direction!
I split my code for web and native and used MemoryRouter in both cases.